# how to select a child of an element with a certain property

Tags: javascript

Does anybody know how I can select all children of an element which have display == block?
I found the jquery children() function which does allow filters, but I haven't figures out yet how to filter for style.display == block?

```
$('#div_id').children('div.style.display == block')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** in jQuery to implement custom filtering function

```js
$('#div_id')
  .children() // get all children
  .filter(function() { // filter with your custom condition here
    return this.style.display == 'block'
  }).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_id">
  <div style="display:block">1</div>
  <div style="display:inline">1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('#div_id').children('div[style="display:block"]');`

Comment: sorry but I get unrecognized expression: div[style=display:block]

Comment: This would only work if the style was applied inline and not via a stylesheet. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/88Lvxpum/

Comment: @carl - It's missing quotes. Should be `[style="display:block"]`